# How to insert latitude and longitude in database from click event?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Using ASP. i am trying to store the user's location (Latitude, Longitude) to a database. This presents the problem:

i want to get values of longitude and latitude of google map by clicking Button i got 0 values in database.. my database ha two filed longitude and latitude which has decimal datatype.

and i also getting this error

> an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-occured-in-system-data-dll in         cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); line

Here's the sample code of my first attempt:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
   <head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var long = 0;
       var lat = 0;
       window.onload = function () {
           var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200),
               zoom: 14,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
               long = e.latLng.lng();
               lat = e.latLng.lat();
               document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
               document.getElementById("lng").value = long;
               alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " + long);
           });
       }
   </script>

<form id="myForm" runat="server">
   <div id="dvMap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
   </div>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lat" runat="server" />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lng" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</form>
</body>
```

And below is the .aspx code-behind file. We save the longitude and latitude to the database during the Click event of the button:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Decimal latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(lat.Value);
        Decimal longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(lng.Value);
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);


        string query1 = "insert into Courses(longi,lati) values (@lati, @longi)";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lati", latitude);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longi", longitude);

                con.Open();

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


                con.Close();    
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to get values from hidden fields in code behind in button1_click ?

Comment: no sir i am nt able to get

Comment: Are the values of `latitude` and `longitude` in your code behind the expected values? Inspect the InnerException of that exception you get - there is probably useful info there. Please [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: i am getting zero vales in database ...i need longitude and latitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be getting value in hidden fields so `null` values are be going to database which is causing error. And you are not getting values in hidden fields because you have made these `runat="server"` so there `ID` get changed and you are setting the values in javascript by `Id` but the `Id` have changed. So what you need to do is set `ClientIDMode` property of hidden fields to `static` like this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="lat"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="lng"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Comment: sir still getting this error An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid object name 'Courses'.(( courses is table name))

Comment: Check the spelling of courses because error suggests that you are giving wrong name of table.

Comment: sit now i ma getting zero values in database

Comment: Because your values are not being set in javascript code there you have declared the default vlaues  `var long = 0;` You are not getting values from `long = e.latLng.lng();`

Comment: then what changes i need to made

Comment: Are you getting values in alert here `alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " + long);`

Comment: Debug and check what values you are getting in button_click ?